# Showing $V(XY) = E(X)^2V(Y)+E(Y)^2V(X)+V(X)V(Y)$

Tags: probability

I tried to reason out the LHS as:

$V(XY) = E(X^2Y^2)-E(XY)^2$

$V(XY) = E(X^2)E(Y^2)-E(X)^2E(Y^2)$

Now I'm not sure how to go about showing that the RHS should be equal to this. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables?

Comment: I removed the tag [tag:combinatorics] from this and another probability-related question of yours.

Comment: @JavaMan, yes, they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent (And thus $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent), we have:

\begin{align}
V(XY) &= E(X^2Y^2) - E(XY)^2
\\
&= E(X^2)E(Y^2) - V(X)V(Y) - E(X)^2E(Y)^2 + V(X)V(Y)
\\
&= E(X^2) E(Y^2) - \big(E(X^2) - E(X)^2 \big)\big(E(Y^2) - E(Y)^2 \big) - E(X)^2 E(Y)^2 + V(X) V(Y)
\\
&= E(X)^2 E(Y^2) + E(X^2) E(Y)^2 - 2E(X)^2 E(Y)^2 + V(X) V(Y)
\\
&= E(X)^2 E(Y^2) - E(X)^2 E(Y)^2 + E(X^2) E(Y)^2 - E(X)^2 E(Y)^2 + V(X) V(Y)
\\
&= E(X)^2 V(Y) + E(Y)^2 V(X) + V(X) V(Y)
\end{align}
as desired.